# добавляется дополнительная ширина к экрану html

Tags: html, css

Почему появляется полоса прокрутки по ширине, как её убрать?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.formSubmit {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.result {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="create.php" method="post" class="formSubmit">
  <label>
            <p>text</p>
            <input type="text" name="text">
            <input type="date" name="date">

            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </label>
</form>

<div class='result'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: width: 100vw; уберите

Comment: Потому что элементы тоже имеют высоту и ширину :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С учетом того, что под вашей формой с 100vh (занимающей весь экран по высоте) ниже лежит ещё и блок div.result, то логичнее всего добавить правило —
`body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`

**upd:** Прошу прощения, забыл сказать, что после того как назначен `flex` для `body`  `.formSubmit` и `.result` больше не нуждаются в `width: 100vw;`. Удалите эти нюансы и всё станет на свои места.

Comment: Полоса прокрутки по ширине к сожалению никуда не делась

Comment: Обновил свой коммент.